# Add a keystore to glassfish

Tags: glassfish, keystore

I am trying to add another keystore in glassfish, however I cannot find a way in the options menu to add one. I want to specify my KS with the relevant password, and alias as well, which I couldn't find under Network config-> Protocols (it doesn't let me specify a PW and alias when adding an SSL configuration to a new protocol).

Should I merge my KS with the existing keystore.jks?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GlassFish supports use of only one keystore file for system configuration. As you say, it is best to merge the keystore entries in one file and then navigate to Network config->Protocols, SSL section and set the cert-nickname to the alias of the certificate you would like to use.

Comment: This is was I ended up doing, actually merged my certificates in the CACERTS.JKS file, because it contains the public certificates used when trying to connect with external parties. 

Thank for the help.